# Improve/optimize LEFT JOIN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a decently long (10 tables, about 60k records each) query, all of those tables are joined using a left join since they could contain null values (all of them).

I'm seeing a huge performance hit and I tracked it down to this bit of code.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MAIN_TABLE d 
LEFT JOIN INSURANCES i on i.IMREDEM_CODE = d.IMREDEM_CODE 
                      and i.INS_TERMINATIONDATE IS NULL 
                      and INS_RANK = 0
                      and i.IMREINS_CODE = (SELECT TOP 1 IMREINS_CODE 
                                              from INSURANCES i2
                                             WHERE i2.IMREDEM_CODE = i.IMREDEM_CODE 
                                               and i2.INS_TERMINATIONDATE IS NULL 
                                               and i2.INS_RANK = 0
                                          ORDER BY TAG_SYSTEMDATE DESC)
```

Basically what I am needing to do is that the insurance table could contain 0 or many records because when they update the insurance it performs an insert not an update for audit purposes.  So I have to join the table twice, on a left join.  Further I need to do this query twice for primary and secondary insurance (primary is rank = 0 and secondary is rank =1.  The IMREDEM_CODE is a PK for the D table and a FK for the i table.

**The answer is here**:

```
left join INSURANCES i on i.IMREDEM_CODE = d.IMREDEM_CODE 
and i.IMREINS_CODE = (SELECT max(imreins_code) FROM INSURANCES i2  WHERE i2.IMREDEM_CODE = i.IMREDEM_CODE and i2.INS_TERMINATIONDATE IS NULL and i2.INS_RANK = 0)
```

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: What indexes do you have on the Insurance table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm sure you may be able to optimize this even further, I have taken a quick stab at it.  Your execution plan will do 3 Table Scans.  You can try this which will reduce that to 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM Main_Table d
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT TOP 1 *
         FROM Insurances 
         WHERE INS_TERMINATIONDATE IS NULL 
             AND INS_RANK = 0
         ORDER BY TAG_SYSTEMDATE DESC) i on i.IMREDEM_CODE = d.IMREDEM_CODE;
```

There is probably a better approach than TOP 1 and Order By, but I'm getting tired and can't think of it at the moment.  Either way, this is definitely more efficient.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8694e/7) with both sets of queries.  You can see the execution plan in each.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I added this and tested the query, took 1:56 to pull back 100 rows.  It took 0:03 using the other approach (basically doing a WHERE IN with the max() expression - this proved to be key instead of returning a bunch of rows then ordering them by date, the last one inserted (highest identity value) is always the most recent, which I forgot about.

Comment: Yeah, I figured there was a better approach than Order by and Top 1 -- just been a long day :-)  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will give you exactly the same result but faster;

```
  SELECT * 
     FROM MAIN_TABLE d 
LEFT JOIN INSURANCES i on i.IMREDEM_CODE = d.IMREDEM_CODE 
                      and i.IMREINS_CODE = select max(i.imreins_code) from INSURANCES
                      and i.INS_TERMINATIONDATE IS NULL
                      and i.INS_RANK = 0
```

Comment: This won't work in SQL Server.  Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8694e/9  -- Max won't work like this

Comment: Basically you can't put the MAX() in a query like that, but what I ended up doing was (again doing 4 table scans)  LEFT JOIN insurance i on .... and i.IMREINS_CODE = SELECT MAX (imreins_code from insurance i2 WHERE ....)  This brought the query time down to 4-5 seconds from 6:30.